# scp speed limit?

Tags: ssh, networking, performance, scp

I am transferring some files between two servers and I can't seem to get past 10.5MB/s (84Mbps). Neither end is being slowed due to encryption according to `htop`; and both internet connections are above 200Mbps. Am I hitting a max speed that `scp` can transfer at?

Comment: No, scp has no artificial speed limit. Are you sure that none of the network between the two servers is congested, you are affected by the relationship of latency and throughput, or you are having your traffic shaped?

Comment: on a 1gbps network, i achieve 112MB/sec transfer rates via samba share.  However I typically see 80-90 MB/sec speeds via *secure copy* `scp` with no other changes.

Comment: *"and both internet connections are above 200mbps"*  re-check your numbers, is it a 10 or 100 or 1000 mbps network?   Be aware of bits per second vs bytes per second.

Comment: @ron: Wi-Fi connections in the range of 200-400 mbps are relatively common now. The actual throughput number fluctuates with the radio noise conditions.

Comment: @ron 200 Mbps (megabits) is what my ISP guarantees. That being said, scp was always much slower than eg. transferring a file over a SSL channel with openssl s_client, etc. Only sfrp was even slower ;-)

Comment: Are you using WinSCP? It [used to have](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6440) a limitation in the internal buffer size that slowed down transfers significantly.

Answer (score 1):

On my local network I use the following ssh parameters

```
-o compression=no,Ciphers=aes128-gcm@openssh.com
```

Which is I think less secure, but it is not an issue in my case, where no other machines on the network. You can give it a try, and choose a cipher what suits your needs. List available ciphers:

```
ssh -Q cipher
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on a wired LAN that is 1gbps, as such I see 112 MB/sec with everything working properly, which correlates to 112 x 8bits/byte = 896 bps.

On that same everything, using *secure copy* `scp` which is using the SSH protocol, I typically see 80-90 MB/sec (according to the text output in the terminal window provided by scp.  I would consider that the max, based on a 1gbps network and estimating the overhead of using secure copy [i.e. ssh].  Figure 85 MB/s = 680 bps.

> and both **internet** connections are above 200mbps...

big problem is what phone company hardware and ISP servers are separating your 2 servers across the internet, any of which can reduce your negotiated connection speed all before scp ever happens.

> 200 Mbps (megabits) is what my ISP guarantees

What may be happening is your hitting **upload** limit of your service plan.  It's likely that your ISP guarantees X download speed, but a Y upload speed.  And I haven't checked in a while, but there may not even be an upload speed guarantee.  Whichever server is initiating the `scp` would be doing *the upload to the internet* while the other receiving server of the secure copy would be seeing *the download from the internet* as far as your ISP is concerned.

a somewhat easy way to validate this is use any free internet service speed test through your web browser.  Run that frequently to know that connection speed but realize it's the transfer rate between you and that specific internet speed test server wherever it is, and not between your two servers which you care about with your scp.

So no there is no limit to the speed at which `scp` can happen.  It will happen as fast as possible that your cpu, ram, disk can process the data and then that your network connection can sustain.

Quick internet search- comcast upload speeds... a 150 mbps plan allows 10-20 mbps uploads.  But you would have to check the fine print, *I suspect upload speeds can be guaranteed for business that specifically pay for it, but for the home user probably not.*

Comment: I think your mixing up my comments with the OPs. But fwiw, mine was just an example -- ssh really seems slower than other protocols (like for instance ssl)